# Regular Drupal 7 site users do not see new tabs added by hook_menu_local_tasks_alter

Tags: nodes, users

I used [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7.x) to add new tab items for node pages like so:

```
function custom_module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  if (arg(0) == 'admin' || arg(0) != 'node') { return; }

  $href='user/'.arg(1).'/hobbies';
  $data['tabs'][0]['output'][] = array(
    '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
    '#link' => array(
      'title' => t('Hobbies'),
      'href' => $href,
    ),
  );
  $href='user/'.arg(1).'/events';
  $data['tabs'][0]['output'][] = array(
    '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
    '#link' => array(
      'title' => t('Events'),
      'href' => $href,
    ),
  );
```

However while admin can see the new tabs, regular users (Drupal 7) do not. Adding `'#access' => TRUE,` to item array does not help as hook_menu_local_tasks_alter doesn't have options for access argument.

And they appear normally if users are given node edit permission.

How can I make access to these new tabs without giving users permission to edit their nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7.x)

So in your module file something like this will do the job. (taken from the hook's page).

```
function hook_permission() {
 return array(
  'administer my module' => array(
  'title' => t('Administer my module'),
  'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
  ),
 );
}
```

When you do that you will get a new entry in your permissions page (admin/people/permissions). Enable that for the anonymous users and it will show up ok.

Comment: Isn't giving module admin permissions to anonymous users is too excessive? :)

Comment: In your case nothing will be administered, but actually the anonymous users will be able to use the functionality of your module.

Comment: that changed nothing by itself, so there is more to do with the hook.

Comment: I am afraid my custom module has to deal with node access hook as no access settings for itself has any effect.